# VS code Terminal Tabs Color

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: 1]

How to change the color of the Terminal Tabs?

Comment: Do you mean the background, if so you can change it with the [color theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes) (Ctrl + k -> Ctrl + T), If not then  check [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) out.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is what you were looking for :)

`"titleBar.activeBackground": "#00FFFF"`

title.background will change the window you were hoping to color but nothing inside of it those all have separate json values like: debug.background, terminal.background etc.